# Post a list of objects with axios?

Tags: reactjs, axios

I am trying to post a list of objects with Axios but I can't get it to work. I am working with a React front-end and a Django (python) backend.

I want to `POST` data like this:

```
[
  {
    invitee: "..."
    party: "..."
  }, {
    invitee: "..."
    party: "..."
  },
  ...
]
```

My first thought was to just take an Array as the data attribute of axios:

```
const res = await authAxios.post(`/conversations/invitations/`, toAPIArr);
```

I also tried to `JSON.stringify` the `Array`, but in the backend I always get an error saying that I am not sending a list. I am doing a simple check (this is python):

```
isinstance(request.data, list) --> always false
```

**Is there something obvious that I am doing wrong here?**

**Edit:** I am using django-rest-framewok on the backend:

**View**

```
class PartyList(APIView):
    def post(self, request, format=None):
        print(isinstance(request.data, list))
        serializer = PartySerializer(data=request.data, many=True)
        user = request.user
        if serializer.is_valid():
            instances = serializer.save(creator=user)
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
```

**Serializer**

```
class PartySerializer(ModelSerializer):
    creator = ReadOnlyField(source='creator.uuid')
    class Meta:
        model = Invitation
        fields = (
            'invitee',
            'party',
        )
        read_only_fields = (
            'uuid',
        )
```

Comment: Please give a [mcve]. Have you looked at the request? Tried an alternative client?

Comment: Could you add your python code?

Comment: hm, woudn't the code above be a minimal reproducible example? I am trying to send a list with axios as the data. So far, I don't know if simply passing an Array is the way to do that. Or wether passing the array like this is correct and the problem lies with the api expecting a different format ...

Comment: I added the python code.

Answer (score 0):

There was one answer to this question that actually got downvoted and deleted that yielded one working solution for me.

It is possible to send an object with axios:

```
const res = await authAxios.post(`/conversations/invitations/`, {list: toAPIArr});
```

From the backend it is then possible to access this list (this is python):

```
arr = request.data.get('list')
```

This is a bit of a hack but so far it works for me. If there is a **right way** (implying that this might be the wrong way) to do this maybe there will be someone who shares it.